# WPF Navigation to be consistent across windows

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

I'm new to using WPF and I'm looking for a way to have a navigation that will be the same across each window. With windows form I would inherit from one form to ensure each window has the same design. Can you do this with WPF or is there a different way to maintain consistency throughout the windows.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this in WPF. If I understand your question correctly, you want to create a custom window template that you can re-use across any new window your application creates.

The way to do this is to create a new custom control that inherits the base class for Window, then customize the new control to fit your needs.

Examples is here:

- https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/140267/Create-Custom-Windows-in-WPF-with-Ease
- https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2013/03/16/how-to-create-a-custom-window-in-wpf/

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use Pages. Then you could put a `<Frame>` tag in your window and by changing the source of the frame with other page to navigate between screens.